# Excel data are strange when MySQL column data has breaklines

Tags: php, excel, csv

I exported MySQL columns data into an excel file through the download concept using the header mechanisms. The problem is that if a column having `text` as its `datatype` has data containing `breaklines` like `enumeration` then the csv file is strange : the enumerated data are placed into different lines in the excel file. So how to make the data placed inside one cell ?

Here is the code of the download :

```
function downloadFile($outPut, $fileName){

        $filesize = strlen($outPut);

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
        header("Content-type: text/enriched");
        header("Content-length: $filesize");
        header("Content-disposition: attachement; filename=$fileName");

        ob_clean();
        flush();

        print($outPut);

        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what a "download concept" actually meant, and told us what file format you are talking about ("an Excel file" is a pretty meaningless statement when Excel has several different file formats). I'm guessing you mean a CSV because that's tagged: are you using fputcsv()?

Comment: Are you using fputcsv()

Comment: Suggest you change the way you approach this to write the data as I've suggested in my answer; using php://output as your filename, and building the output as I've shown in your downloadFile function rather than simply passing it all through pre-formatted

Comment: the problem is that the data are not static like in your example, but they are from database. So how to use fputcsv in that case for the download ? NB : the file will be created on the fly by the download but not in my code.

Comment: The data arrays in my fputcsv() example could just as easily be rowdata arrays returned by a database query

Comment: The real problem is how to use fputcsv with the header directives ?

Comment: There's plenty of ways you could do this: output the header documents before looping through your database rows and writing them; loop through the database rows fputcsv'ing them to a temp file, then simply passing that temp file to the downloadFile() function with its headers; loop through the database rows fputcsv'ing them to php://output but with output buffering, and then writing that output buffer in your downloadFile() function; passing an array of rows to downloadFile(), then doing all the fputcsv() logic there.... that's 4 different suggestions that would all work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty method is to use a "\r\n" as the actual row ending in the CSV file; and a simple "\n" as the breakline within a cell, making sure that you quote any cell values that contain the breakline.

```
$fh = fopen('test.csv', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, "sep=\t" . "\r\n");
fwrite($fh, 'A' ."\t" . 'B' . "\t" . 'C' . "\r\n");
fwrite($fh, 'D' ."\t" . "\"E\nF\nG\"" . "\t" . 'H' . "\r\n");
fclose($fh);
```

This example uses a tab separator between cells; and shows a three-line value in cell B2

**EDIT**

Or using fputcsv()

```
$fh = fopen('test2.csv', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, "sep=\t" . PHP_EOL);
fputcsv($fh, array('A', 'B', 'C'), "\t");
fputcsv($fh, array('D', "E\nF\nG", 'H'), "\t");
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to ensure that each of the fields you are exporting are within double quotes if they are not already, this will save a lot of formatting issues e.g. with commas within a field etc. If you are still having problems I would suggest trying to replace the newline characters with something that you will interpret as a new line (or just as space). Try this in your sql (around the field that ,ay have newline characters:

```
REPLACE(your_column_name,'\n',' ')
```